# How to overwrite Spring properties files in build directory?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot and Gradle project. I defined the app version in the gradle.properties file from where Gradle can read it. I'd like to have this number in the application code, as a `@Value("${version}")` injected value.

What I am trying to do is to copy the version number into application.properties or a separate version.properties file (both located in src/main/resources.
Actually, I want to load the properties file into a Properties object, set the 'app.verion' property and then write it out. Ideally all these steps would be done on the file in the build dir ($buildDir/resources/main/version.properties). This way I don't need to store this dinamically set variable in the VCS. Unfortunately the thing only works if I write the properties file in the source directory. If I try to edit the one in build, then it doesn't have any effect.

Could you help me? When should my task ran? I have the feeling that Spring might overwrite the file in build.

My code is:

```
task appendVersionToApplicationProperties << {
    //  File versionPropsFile = new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties")
    versionPropsFile.withWriter { w ->
        Properties p = new Properties()
        versionPropsFile.withInputStream {
            p.load(it)
        }
        p['app.version'] = appVersion // this is from gradle.properties
        p.store w, null
    }
}

build.finalizedBy(appendVersionToApplicationProperties)
```

Output of gradle build:

```
$ gradle clean build
:clean
:compileJava
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:appendVersionToApplicationProperties UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:findMainClass
:war
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 27.16 secs
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
task appendVersionToApplicationProperties {
    // write your properties
    // this is just basic groovy code
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.put('app.version', appVersion) // get it from wherever
    def file = new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties")
    file.createNewFile()
    props.store(file.newWriter(), null)
}

// this will run your task after the java compilation and resource processing
processResources.finalizedBy appendVersionToApplicationProperties
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The task does the trick, I tested it running alone. But if I run gradle clean build, the version.properties file is not in the build directory. I suppose it is overwritten by one of the tasks, I just cannot figure out which one.

Comment: @vargen_ attach gradle build output to your question and perhaps a bit more of your build.gradle file

Comment: I added my build output. My build.gradle file is a basic Spring Boot one plus two custom tasks which aren't run on build. What part would be interesting?